# Key functionality is disappearing

Tags: keyboard, hardware, super-key

I have literally no clue what is happening or why.

My computer is relatively new (a couple of months old). I'm running Ubuntu 20.04. I keep the computer in pretty good shape (don't do anything crazy with it, don't eat over it, if it leaves the house it's in a bag, etc.) Recently, and for no good reason, the super key (the Windows key) just stopped functioning. Thinking it was a hardware issue, I opened the console and ran `showkey`, which showed that when I pressed the key, the console logged `keycode 240 press` and `keycode 240 release`. So it's not a hardware issue--the key still works. But the bindings aren't working, and when I press it on its own--which should display all open windows--nothing happens.

What happened here and why? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've discovered that there is a second "mode" for the super key, which is reached by the `Fn-SuperKey` combination. When `Fn-SuperKey` is pressed, the super key will "flash" each time it is pressed, instead of maintaining a sustained input. Pressing `Fn-SuperKey` again will release that "mode" and return functionality to normal.
I'll continue doing some research as to exactly what this functionality is and why it is exists, but that is what is happening and why.