# How to remap Super key properly

Tags: xorg, keyboard, xmodmap

I don't know why, but I've needed to remap my super key. It got erased somehow.

I logged the keypress as 248 using `xev`, then used `xmodmap -e "keycode 248 = Super_L"` just to make sure the right key was mapped, and then I set `mod4` using `xmodmap -e "add mod4 = Super_L"`.

That set the left super key as super. But when I tried to press and hold the super key, the system doesn't recognize the hold. Too confirm this, I opened `showkey`, which confirms that `keycode 240 release` immediately follows `keycode 240 press` with no delay.

How do I set the system to recognize a hold of the key, rather than an immediate press-release? I need this functionality in order to use super shortcuts, obviously.

Comment: Does this happen with other keys, that is if you press and hold the space or 'a' key does xev show a release event for the space or 'a'?

Comment: @icarus The release event only occurs when I actually release the other keys.

Comment: does it persist after system restart? what is the output of the _xmodmap_ command?

Comment: In particular if you unplug the keyboard and plug it back in does it help?

Comment: @Andra It happens arbitrarily. Last night my machine was working fine. Today the issue has cropped back up. There's no rhyme or reason.

Comment: @icarus It's a laptop, I can't easily unplug or replug the keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you answered your own question here:
[Key functionality is disappearing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/617712/key-functionality-is-disappearing/633317#633317)

The solution is to press Fn+Super_L.

It seems that pressing Fn+Super_L toggles the mode of this key between "holding enabled" and "immediate release". At least on this range of laptops. Notice there might be a small lock icon on the key.

It's probable that Fn+Super_L was pressed by mistake.

Also, note that `xmodmap -pm -pke | grep Super_L` displays (among other lines):
`keycode 133 = Super_L (...)`, so there is already a key mapped to Super_L. The keycode 248 is something else, initially mapped to nothing.